# Most efficient way to show a loading spinner - Android

Tags: android, android-view

I am building an app that contains a lot of views that need to be loaded from a remote server. Therefore, a loading spinner like [this one](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/118082i204C32E01666789C?v=v2) will be used as a placeholder for it until it's fully loaded. This is how I am doing it :

1- First, I use a `spinner.gif` file which I placed in the `res/raw` folder. I am really not restricted to only this file. I want any spinner view/animation that shows there is something that is being loaded.

2- Then, I literally added `Glide` as a dependency just to show these GIFs. The library itself takes up a considerable space of my app size. This is the code I use:

```
val gif = findViewById<ImageView>(rr.id.gif)
=Glide.with(context)
            .asGif()
            .load(rr.raw.spinner)
            .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
            .listener(object : RequestListener<GifDrawable?> {
                override fun onLoadFailed(
                    e: GlideException?,
                    model: Any?,
                    target: Target<GifDrawable?>?,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {
                    return false
                }

                override fun onResourceReady(
                    resource: GifDrawable?,
                    model: Any?,
                    target: Target<GifDrawable?>?,
                    dataSource: DataSource?,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {
                    resource?.setLoopCount(999999999)
                    return false
                }
            })
            .into(gif)
```

I believe this is overkill just to load a spinner GIF. Is there a more efficient way to show a spinner animation (of any kind) that saves me in terms of performance and app size? I have tried using ProgressBar but it's just a horizontal bar that loads according to the values passed to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a `ProgressBar` is a circular, indeterminate one (i.e. it doesn't show an amount of progress, it just spins to show activity). Just stick one in your layout with a width and height and that's all you need! You can see some options for customising it (including with your own drawable) on [the docs page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar).

If you like, the Material Components library [has its own progress spinners](https://material.io/components/progress-indicators/android) - for those you *do* need to set `indeterminate` to true, they're determinate by default.

Comment: Amazing. The Material Component one worked as expected. I am not sure why the default progress bar was horizontal and was a pain to use. This seems much more convenient. Thank you very much.

Comment: @chromaticnoob did you copy and paste someone's example code? I threw one in a layout just to check and it's a spinny circle, you need to explicitly apply the `Horizontal` style to make it a bar